# set difference operator not taking difference (appears to do nothing)?

Tags: python, h2o

Trying to do a simple `set` difference in python, and getting results that indicate the the difference operator is doing nothing. Eg. have code

python version 2.7.15+

```py
    assert isinstance(left_frame, h2o.H2OFrame)
    assert isinstance(right_frame, h2o.H2OFrame)
    assert isinstance(left_key, str)
    assert isinstance(right_key, str)

    # ensure that the primary_key exists in both frames
    assert left_key in left_frame.columns, 'left_key: {} does not exist in left_frame'.format(left_key)
    assert right_key in right_frame.columns, 'right_key: {} does not exist in right_frame'.format(right_key)

    # ensure that the primary_key is the only common column between the left and right frame
    left_non_pk_cols = set(left_frame.columns) - set(left_key)
    assert left_on not in left_non_pk_cols, '%s' % left_key
    right_non_pk_cols = set(right_frame.columns) - set(right_key)
    assert right_on not in right_non_pk_cols, '%s' % right_key
    left_non_pk_cols_in_right = left_non_pk_cols.intersection(right_non_pk_cols)
    assert len(left_non_pk_cols_in_right) == 0,\
        'The primary_key is not the only common column between frames, h2o merge will not work as expected\n%s\n%s\n%s' \
        % (left_non_pk_cols, right_non_pk_cols, left_non_pk_cols_in_right)
```

I get the error

```py
    assert left_key not in left_non_pk_cols, '%s' % left_key
AssertionError: <the left_key value>
```

This is really weird to me. Running in a terminal (with same python version) for a simplified example case

```py
assert u'1' not in (set([u'1', u'2', u'3']) - set(u'1'))
# noting that the H2OFrames `.columns` field is a list of unicode strings
```

throws no error at all and completes as expected (when printing the resulting `set`, everything looks as it should (no `u'1'` element)).

Using the `.difference()` method rather than the `-` operator does not result in any difference either.

Does anyone know what could be going on here or other things to do to get more debugging info?

Comment: I don't see that assertion in the code you posted.

Comment: Try changing `set(left_key)` to `set([left_key])`. If `left_key` is iterable, you're making a set of its elements, not the object itself.

Comment: @Barmar Will see; I don't see why that would work though, since using a unicode string in the simplified example **did work** without putting the unicode value in a list. Could you let me know what you're thinking on what the change would be fixing (and what would currently be going wrong without it)?

Comment: A string is an iterable whose elements are the characters. Since your example string only has one character, there's no difference between `set(u'1')` and `set([u'1'])`. Try `set(u'23')` and you'll see the difference.

Comment: For instance, `set("abc")` produces the set `{"a", "b", "c"}`, not `{"abc"}`.

Comment: @Barmar That worked, thanks. (Guess I made my test case example too simplified; was getting me really confused). If you copy this into an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Barmar I think a `set` literal (`{left_key}`) would be more concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `set()` is an iterable, and it creates a set of each element of the iterable. So if `left_key` is a string, `set(left_key)` will create a set of each of the unique characters of the string, not a set whose element is the string.

The solution is to use `set([left_key])`. The argument will be the list, and the set will then contain its single element, the string. Or you can just use a set literal `{left_key}`

```
left_non_pk_cols = set(left_frame.columns) - {left_key}
```

Another way is to just remove the element from the set.

```
left_non_pk_cols = set(left_frame.columns)
left_non_pk.cols.discard(left_key)
```

I used `discard` rather than `remove` because it doesn't signal an error if the element isn't found.